# The method 'xxx' cannot be the method for an event because a class this class derives from already defines the method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a code:

```
public class Layout : UserControl
{    
    protected void DisplayX_DisplayClicked(object sender, DisplayEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentDisplay = (CameraPanel)sender;
    }
}
```

'Layout' is a base class for my other layouts. For example, I have a 'Layout1' derived from base class 'Layout'. Layout1 has an element Display01. Display01 has an DisplayClicked event. I'm trying to assign DisplayX_DisplayClicked via Visual Studio Designer to DisplayClicked event of Display01.

```
public partial class Layout1 : Layout
{
    private CameraPanel Display01;
}
```

It gives me an error:

*The method 'xxx' cannot be the method for an event because a class this class derives from already defines the method.*

How to use method from base class as a eventhandler of derived class ? Is it possible ? If so, how. If no, why.

Comment: I don't repro this at all.  What *exactly* do you type?

Comment: @Hans, You can't reproduce ? OK, step-by-step. 1. Add new Base class Layout:UserControl. 2. Add method DisplayX_DisplayClicked(object sender, DisplayEventArgs e) with empty body to base class. 3. Add derived class Layout1:Layout. 4. Add some control to Layout1, for example I added CameraPanel Display01. Display01 have an event DisplayClicked. I want to add an eventhandler to Display01.DisplayClicked via Visual Studio Designer.I want to use a method from base class for that goal. But vs designer deny it. ___ I want to add an event handler via visual studio designeer not manual.

Comment: You didn't say what you typed.

Comment: ahmmm, What did I type in property grid in Visual Studio Designer ? I was trying to type DisplayX_DisplayClicked there and then messagebox with "property is not valid" appears ... in Details in shows an error which in a title of this question ...

Comment: Something is very strange here.  I was on a trip, I committed this "sin" and got away with it.  No squawks, the program compiled and ran.  I got home and flipped everything onto my main machine and it started screaming and I started Googling and found this thread.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The designer can't handle that, but you can do it in code just fine.  In the constructor for Layout1, just write:

```
public Layout1()
{   
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Display01.DisplayClicked += base.DisplayX_DisplayClicked;
}
```

Alternately, you could let the designer generate a method named Display01_DisplayClicked, and then implement it as:

```
private void Display01_DisplayClicked(object sender, DisplayEventArgs e)
{
    base.DisplayX_DisplayClicked(sender, e);
}
```

That's a lot more verbose, so I would do it the first way, but it would let the designer be aware that there was a handler for that event.

Comment: Why don't Visual Studio Designer allow to use base class method ?

Comment: because designer search only in the current class.

Comment: I'll use your solution with base.xxx ... however, it's not very good, because i can't see these handlers in visual studio designer. If another programmer will look at a usercontrol in visual studio desinger => he wouldn't see nothing (anything?).

@serhio, bad studia. but at the other hand, should vs designer look at the whole hierarchy ? maybe should, and maybe shouldn't ...

Comment: You can even use the exactly same method name if you make it `protected override`, see the other answer. However, overriding does not work if a custom, generic EventArgs class is used. VS Designer is very poor on handling generics.

Answer (score 4):

Designer looks only for methods in the class you're editing. To workaround this issue you can overwrite the method in your subclass and just call the base method. It will work just fine in the designer.

```
    protected override void DisplayX_DisplayClicked(object sender, DisplayEventArgs e)
    {
        base.DisplayX_DisplayClicked(sender, e);
    }
```

Comment: works great, but fails if the EventArgs class is a generic class.