# C# Designer error for derive method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem when I open the designer in Visual Studio for my form

> The method 'dragScreen_MouseDown' cannot be the method for an event because a class this class derives from already defines the method.

Only thing I changed was adding a new class named `FormBase` and get the methods from that class to other forms. Works fine, but designer does not seem to like it.

So in `FormBase.cs` i got this method:

```
protected void dragScreen_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ReleaseCapture();
        SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
    }
}
```

Then in `Main.cs` inherit form FormBase.

In the designer it like this:

```
this.button6.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.dragScreen_MouseDown);
```

Comment: Please show us the code

Comment: I have no idea what to show, since the method itself is not the problem. Just the desinger which does not seem to like it. I found similar issue here but it did not work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165269/the-method-xxx-cannot-be-the-method-for-an-event-because-a-class-this-class-de

Comment: So you added a new class like `class FormBase : Form1`?

Comment: declare the method with the 'new' keyword, or re-name the method.

Comment: @qjnr more like class MainForm : BaseForm

Comment: @DanielleSummers what do you mean?

Comment: Without seeing the code of your derived class and in particular the method that causes the issue it´s impossible to guess what goes whrong.

Comment: If you want to override your method, you need to make it abstract and use `override` keyword

Comment: I updated main post, thing is everything works fine. It's just the desinger which display that error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The method 'xxx' cannot be the method for an event because a class this class derives from already defines the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165269/the-method-xxx-cannot-be-the-method-for-an-event-because-a-class-this-class-de)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you've derived the *partial* class `MainForm` from the class `BaseForm`, wich is derived from the class `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. This means the designer generated code i derived from the class `System.Windows.Forms.Form` but your part of the class is `BaseForm`. You need to change the designer code from `public partial class MainForm : Form` to `public partial class MainForm : BaseForm`.

Am I right??

Comment: It's already like that. The application run fines with no errors. It's just the desinger in my MainForm that show the error.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use that `BaseForm` because Visual Studio doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. Due to i had dragScreen in the Main.Designer.cs which cause the first conflict that it does not like looking for method outside the class. So i had to remove those lines and add in the Main.cs constructer:

```
panel4.MouseDown += dragScreen_MouseDown;
```